# Author archive custom posts only?

Tags: custom-post-types, author

I am using the function below to try and display custom post type 'direct_blog posts only. However for some reason it is also displaying standard posts and I don't know why?

Your help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
   function blogs_custom_author_archives_posts_per_page($query) {

       if (!is_admin() && $query->is_main_query()) {
           if ($query->is_author()) {
                $query->set('post_type', array('direct_blog'));
                $query->set('posts_per_page', 5);
            }
        }
    }
    add_action('pre_get_posts', 'blogs_custom_author_archives_posts_per_page');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to only query posts from the post-type `direct_blog`, but **NOT** the normal `post` type?

Than you simply need to remove `post` from this line:

```
$query->set('post_type', array('post', 'direct_blog'));
```

---

**Update:**

I just tested the following code.

First you need to revisit your function, as you have some errors in it.
In the code in your question, you are missing a closing `}`!
Than you are also using `posts_per_page`, but you are missing the "`s`", in your function it is `post_per_page`.

So I believe you want something like this:

```
function my_pre_get_posts( $query ) {

    if (!is_admin() && $query->is_main_query()) {

        if ($query->is_author()) {

            $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'my_type' ));
            $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 5 );

        }
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_pre_get_posts' );
```

As I said above, this code is working in my WP testsite, Iam not seeing normal posts, just posts from `my_type` in my author archiv template.
So try to change `my_type` to your post type (make sure that `direct_blog` is the right slug)

Comment: Thanks but I already tried that and it still also shows standard posts?

Comment: @ianhman I added a update to my answer with code I just tested. It is working for my. Please check your function again as I saw that there are atleast 2 errors in it.

Comment: Thanks again however it stills displays the standard blog posts :(
(I updated my answer to correct typos in code)

Comment: @ianhman OK I tested it again. I copied your updated code and just changed the `direct_blog` to `my-type`. Nothing else.  And this is still working in my theme. I just see posts from `my-type` and no normal posts. So sorry, maybe try activating another theme and see if this code is working. And you are also sure you are viewing an author archiv yes?

Comment: Thanks for all your help. In the end it turns out there was some conflicting code in another function that was causing the standard posts to show, doh!